# Semantic Mediawiki #ask query with long result

Tags: mediawiki, semantics, mediawiki-templates, semantic-mediawiki

I use Semantic Mediawiki and Semantic Forms.

I made a form that uses *subobjects*. So for showing on Mediawiki page the text that user has written in my form - I use `#ask` query and wiki template. My ask code is like this:

```
{{#ask: [[-Has subobject::{{FULLPAGENAME}}]]
   |?MyProperty1
   |?MyProperty2
   |format=template
   |template=MyTemplateLayout
   |introtemplate=MyTemplateLayoutHeader
   |outrotemplate=MyTemplateLayoutFooter
   |named args=yes
   }}
```

It works when user's text in the form is small. But if text has enters, bullets or `<br>` tag inside it - query result is empty:
[image]

Is it possible to configure or hide the long text in my forms to make working query result? How can I do it?

Just in case - my template code is:

```
   {{#if:{{{?MyProperty1|}}} {{{?MyProperty2|}}}|
   {{!}}- style="background-color: WhiteSmoke;"
   {{!}}{{{?MyProperty1|}}}{{!}}{{!}}{{{?MyProperty2|}}}
   {{!}}-
   }}
```

And my Form code is like:

```
   {{{for template|MySubobject|multiple|add button text=Добавить|embed in field=Test[TestField]}}}
   {{{field|MyProperty1|input type=textarea|cols=90|rows=1|autogrow=true}}}||{{{field|MyProperty2|input type=textarea|cols=90|rows=1|autogrow=true}}}
   ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ensure that your property has type Text ( create page `Property:MyProperty` with contents `[[has type::Text]]` ).